# Email not sending smtpJS

Tags: javascript, html, email, html-email, smtpjs

Trying to send an email from an HTML Form. I have followed the instructions to use smtpJS and elastic email. When I click the submit button on my form I just get an alert that says "OK" and a status of 200. However, I do not receive an email. Has anyone else ran into this?

```
  function sendEmail()
  {
    Email.send({
      SecureToken : "secure token here",
      To : "azenk22@gmail.com",
      From : "azenk@nicoletcollege.edu",
      Subject : "This is the subject",
      Body : "And this is the body"
     }).then(
      message => alert(message)
     );  
  }
```